# Unable to run jmeter with dashboard option from linux

Tags: linux, jmeter, dashboard

I'm trying to create the dashboard option from the Non-GUI command line in Linux. I'm using the latest version 3.0. It runs fine on windows, but when I try to run it from Linux:

```
jmeter -n -t test-file [-p property-file] [-l log-file] -e -o [Path to output folder]
```

I get the following **error**:

```
Error: Unknown option -e
```

At first, I thought an older version was installed, so I tried to install a newer version, but I got:

```
sudo apt-get install jmeter
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
jmeter is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So which version are you using on your Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

Run `jmeter -v` command and check the output, you should see something like:

```
$ ./jmeter -v
Writing log file to: /private/tmp/bin/jmeter.log
    _    ____   _    ____ _   _ _____       _ __  __ _____ _____ _____ ____
   / \  |  _ \ / \  / ___| | | | ____|     | |  \/  | ____|_   _| ____|  _ \
  / _ \ | |_) / _ \| |   | |_| |  _|    _  | | |\/| |  _|   | | |  _| | |_) |
 / ___ \|  __/ ___ \ |___|  _  | |___  | |_| | |  | | |___  | | | |___|  _ <
/_/   \_\_| /_/   \_\____|_| |_|_____|  \___/|_|  |_|_____| |_| |_____|_| \_\ 3.0 r1743807

Copyright (c) 1999-2016 The Apache Software Foundation
```

Mind that **3.0 r1743807** bit. If you have major version <3 - you won't have any dashboard.

In regards to this

> jmeter is already the newest version

message - it doesn't necessarily mean that you have the newest JMeter version installed, it means you don't have an upgrade candidate. JMeter is not essential package so keeping its version up-to-date is up to your maintainers.

So take the next steps:

1. Make sure you have JDK or JRE version not less than 7 installed. Ways to check are:

   - executing `java --version` command
   - using [apt-show-version](http://Another%20way%20to%20check%20installed%20package%20version%20is%20running%20%60apt-show-versions%20jmeter%60%20command.)
2. Download the [latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and follow steps from [5 Key Things You Need to Know About JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) article for installation instructions.
3. Once downloaded make sure you executing the new version of JMeter like `./jmeter` from its "bin" folder as running `jmeter` will bring the old version. The alternative ways are

   - adding it to PATH prior to version you get from package manager like:

     ```
     PATH=/opt/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin:$PATH && export PATH
     ```
   - removing old JMeter version like:

     ```
     apt-get remove jmeter
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Silly question , did you install all the needed plugins ? if it is a linux server you can install the plugins via console
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/

Comment: Dont put "silly question" into an answer ... that really diminishes the value of your answer. Simply state that "missing plugins" could explain/solve the issue.